# How to extract only the first element of each element in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
[[1, 2], [5, 3], [7, 2]]
```

I want to extract the first of each element, i.e., get an output like this:

```
[1,5,7]
```

How to do that?

Comment: Use a list comprehension.

Comment: Wow, all of us just jumped on that one. But seriously, a list comprehension is what you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using list comprehension:

```
my_list = [[1, 2], [5, 3], [7, 2]]
my_new_list = [ x[0] for x in my_list ]
```

demo:

```
>>> my_list = [[1, 2], [5, 3], [7, 2]]
>>> my_list[0]
[1,2]
>>> my_list[0][0]
1
```

simple without list comprehension:

```
my_list = [[1, 2], [5, 3], [7, 2]]
my_new_list = []
for x in my_list:
    my_new_list.append(x[0])
```

using `lambda` and `map`:

```
# python 2x
my_new_list = map(lambda x:x[0],my_list)
#python 3x
my_new_list = list(map(lambda x:x[0],my_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension. For instance:

```
old_list = [[1,2], [5,3], [7,2]]
new_list = [sublist[0] for sublist in old_list]
```

Alternatively you can use `map` with `operator.itemgetter`.

```
import operator

old_list = [[1,2], [5,3], [7,2]]
new_list = map(operator.itemgetter(0), old_list)
## in python3
# new_list = list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), old_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension:

```
my_list = [[1, 2], [5, 3], [7, 2]]
new_list = [x[0] for x in my_list]
```